# ng-click not working in IE but works fine in CHROME

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
<select id="from" multiple="multiple" name="list" ng-model="selectedVal">
    <optgroup label= "{{geo.Geo}}" ng-repeat="geo in Geographies"> 
        <option id="{{country.CountryKey}}" ng-repeat="country in geo.Country" ng-click="arrayPush()">{{country.CountryDescription}}</option>   
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

arrayPush() is not being called when I am clicking a specific option

```
$scope.arrayPush = function(){alert("Hello!");}
```

Comment: IE can be very strict sometimes and i could bet it just doesnt allow onclock on option element, try moving it to the select and there find the selected ect.

Answer (score 1):

I just found-out the answer to my question

```
<select id="from" multiple="multiple" name="list" ng-model="selectedVal" ng-change="arrayPush()">
    <optgroup label= "{{geo.Geo}}" ng-repeat="geo in Geographies"> 
        <option id="{{country.CountryKey}}" ng-repeat="country in geo.Country" >{{country.CountryDescription}}</option>   
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Instead of using ng-click in option, use an ng-model and ng-change in select. Works in both Chrome and IE