# ng-click not working in IE but working in other browsers like chrome,safari,firefox

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my code. Just simply trying to put login action using angularjs. Its working in other browsers. But not working in IE only. How can i fix this?

```
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control inputValue" id="inputEmail" ng-model="LoginEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control inputValue" id="inputPassword" ng-model="LoginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="btnAdminLogin()">Login</button>
```

Comment: What version of angular & what version of IE?

Comment: Hope you have gone through these: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210546/ng-click-not-working-in-ie-but-works-fine-in-chrome

Comment: @Ed Hinchliffe using AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.7

Comment: @Pam yes, i followed. But still its not working. One more thing ng-change is not useful in button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rely on your code working in old versions of internet explorer, you need to use angular v 1.2.x, not angular v 1.3.x.

As detailed in [this blog post](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html):

> AngularJS 1.3 discontinues support for Internet Explorer 8